# Code to loop goalseek pops error if the cell is blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code to loop goalseek. It is popping an error if the cell is blank.

```vb
Sub Button2_Click()
'
' Button2_Click Macro
'

Dim i As Integer
For i = 13 To 2000

    Range("AS" & i).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("AS" & i).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("AL" & i)
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 2")).Select
Next i

End Sub
```

How to modify below code I found into my code above?

```vb
For i = 13 To 49 
    Cells(i, 4).Select 
    If Cells(i, 4).Value <> "" Then 
        code.... 
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Button2_Click()
'
' Button2_Click Macro
'

Dim i As Integer
For i = 13 To 2000
    If Range("AS" & i).Select <> "" Then
        Range("AS" & i).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("AS" & i).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("AL" & i)
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 2")).Select
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```